# Datatables, how to bind event on all rows of the table

Tags: jquery, datatables

My datatable is working fine except the fact that i am trying to add a `dblclick` functionality on each row, which that works partially.

So, this is my code:

```
oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
});

/* Add a click handler to the rows */

//This highlights the row selected
$("#example tbody").click(function(event) {
        $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
                $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
        });
        $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
});

//this attaches a dblclick event on the row
$("#example tr").dblclick(function() {
        var iPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData( iPos );
        var iId = aData[1];
        $('#edit'+iId).click(); //clicks a button on the first cell
});
```

The highlighting of rows is ok for all rows of the tables, but the `dblclick` is working ONLY for the rows that where initially rendered in the first page. When I sort/search data and the data displayed change, the `dblclick` event does not work for those rows that where not displayed in the first page.

Can anyone help to solve this mystery?
Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The first answer is near perfect, but has to have one little tweak that stops it from working.

As in the jquery apidoc [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you have to add the `[, selector ]` as i did below with the `"tr"`

```
$("#example").on("dblclick", "tr", function() {
        var iPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData( iPos );
        var iId = aData[1];
        $('#edit'+iId).click(); //clicks a button on the first cell
});
```

Comment: At the api page search for `Direct and delegated events` and read through it. Hope it helps you out.

Comment: Thanks very much, i found a very good explanation here also http://stackoverflow.com/a/8111171/1387157

Answer (score 3):

in case you need a different but similar scenario to bind to all specific classes inside datatable  see below sample

```
$("#sample_2 tbody").on("click", "a.ApproveLink", approveLinkHandler);
```

also consider following official doc about this issue:

> One of the best ways of dealing with this is through the use of
>   **delegated events** with jQuery's on method

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  $("#example tbody").on("click",function(event) {
        $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
                $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
        });
        $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
});


  $("#example tr").on("dblclick",function() {
            var iPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData( iPos );
            var iId = aData[1];
            $('#edit'+iId).click(); //clicks a button on the first cell
    });
```

we can use events directly on the data which will load when the page is loading.Othersise we need to use **on.**

Comment: nop! it still doesn't work. Again only the first page rows are bound to an event and not the whole dataset